# How to fetch or view executed hive queries on hive metadata

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, cloudera, navigator

I have configured mysql as metastore to hive and i am able to view hive
tables,columns,partitions in sql . Simillarly,i need to view the hive
queries executed on hive data.

When i run the hive query in hive shell, the query is stored in
hive history file at default location.Since my metastore is mysql for hive
whenever i create a table with some columns in hive shell,it gets populated
in sql metastore database.

I want to view the hive queries over a period of time populated in a sql table, but not through the web browser. I found cloudera navigator where they show hive queries on lineage diagram.

Can anyone suggest me some idea on this scenario. I mean can i fetch those executed sql queries using java/jdbc.

Comment: Refer similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66134531/14226243) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66365719/14226243)